# Detect bluetooth connection (android sdk ICS)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to build a small App that will recognize any Bluetooth headset connection and disconnection and write it to log file.

I tried to use [android SDK example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#Profiles) for detecting Bluetooth connection but it's not working.
When my application is loading I am getting a call to OnServiceConnected and that's about it. no other calls to OnServiceConnected or to OnServiceDisconnected when i am connecting and disconnecting by Bluetooth headsets (I tired more then one).

I wrote all the code in the OnCreate function.

Maybe the problem is with android 4?
Or is it anything else?

```
// Get the default adapter
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

// Establish connection to the proxy.
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this.getApplicationContext(), mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
       // Write to log - OnServiceConnected
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
       // Write to log - OnServiceDisconnected 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it.

Here is it:

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                    new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                    new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
            {
                // LOG - Connected
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action))
            {
                // LOG - Disconnected
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct still i will add you your answer the need to add the bluetooth permission to the android manifest.
'<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />'

Comment: `action` is `String action = intent.getAction();`